# Adding elements to the DOM via ajax and keeping jQuery connected

Tags: jquery, jquery-on, jquery-events

I have always had an issue in case when elements added to the DOM through AJAX don't seem to get the relevant `jQuery.on()` handlers attached to them. So I ended up with re-adding the events to them in the AJAX complete function.

But I always wondered if `jQuery.on()` should be attaching to them and if so then why isn't it?

Comment: Just read more carefully `on()` documentation, that's clearly explained

Comment: Read about delegated events. `on()` uses delegated events and will apply to any elements added to the DOM later provided you use the right selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different kinds of event bindings in jQuery.

The code below will attach `click` event only to the currently available DOM elements, and on removal or re-addition of the elements, the event will work no more

```
$(".myElement").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Clicked!");
})
```

The below method will attach `click` event to all the elements with the given selector for the whole lifecycle of the DOM, irrespective of addition and removal of the elements any number of times.

```
$(document).on("click", ".myElement", function() {
    console.log("Clicked!");
})
```

Comment: that worked thanks. Should I attach all my events the second way in future or is it more costly to do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery you're using?

Previously, before 1.9 there was a `jQuery.live()` - [API docs link](https://api.jquery.com/live/) to add event handlers to the elements that did't exist in the DOM yet. But since 1.7 `jQuery.on()` - [API docs link](https://api.jquery.com/on/) works in the same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

How you used `on` method? what is the version of `jQuery` that you using? instead of `on`, you can use `delegate` as well. [here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is more info about `delegate`

Comment: It seems that you got the answer :)